# How do I connect my Spotify App to Facebook Connect?

Tags: javascript, facebook, spotify

I am developing a Spotify App and everything goes very well with a lot of reverse engineering and inspecting the javascript objects from the inspector. However, I can't seem to manage to get the Facebook connect code working.

I have tried using the Facebook Javascript `FB.init()` and then FB.login but the domain is sp://myidentifier which isn't a valid domain for Facebook.

I see that other apps have managed to get this working so I am sure it works. The best way would be if there were any built in methods for doing this since Spotify is well connected to Facebook to start with?

I really appreciate any help I can get. From today I can't inspect any other apps than my own which otherwise could have put me in the right direction.

Comment: I just got a comment from Spotify:

"I can't find this in the docs, but try something like:"

sp.core.showAuthDialog(auth_url, close_url, callbacks)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the auth module instead. sp.core is a private object and will not pass the approval stage for submitting an app on App Finder.

```
var sp = getSpotifyApi(1);
var auth = sp.require('sp://import/scripts/api/auth');

auth.authenticateWithFacebook('MY_APP_ID', ['user_about_me', 'user_checkins'], {

    onSuccess : function(accessToken, ttl) {
        console.log("Success! Here's the access token: " + accessToken);
    },

    onFailure : function(error) {
        console.log("Authentication failed with error: " + error);
    },

    onComplete : function() { }
});
```

https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/beta/09321954e7.html

Comment: Sorry, my Spotify version (0.8.0.1035) can't find the auth module. 
_error: Failed to read "sp://import/scripts/api/auth.js"_

Comment: I found this link from another thread asking the same question: http://developer.spotify.com/blog/archives/2012/01/12/new-spotify-api-preview-build-available/

Answer (score 7):

I was faster than Stackoverflow this time ;)

This is the code I ended up with:

```
var appID = "1234567890";
var path = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?';
var successUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";

var queryParams = [
    'client_id=' + appID,
    'redirect_uri=' + successUrl,
    'display=popup',
    'scope=email,read_stream',
    'response_type=token'
    ];

var query = queryParams.join('&');
var url = path + query;         

sp.core.showAuthDialog(url, successUrl, {                   
    onSuccess : function(response) {
        console.log('success', response);

        // response contains access token in hashstring
        var queryPart = response.split("#")[1];
        var queryStrings = queryPart.split("&");
        accessToken = queryStrings[0].split('=')[1];

        // we will use the token to get the rest of the user data                                   
        $.getJSON('https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=' + accessToken + '&callback=?', function(facebookUser){
            console.log('logged in user: ', facebookUser);                          

            // TODO: add logic to handle the user here


        });


    }
});
```

Comment: How did you figure this out?  I don't see any of the sp.core functions documented in the JavaScript API reference: http://developer.spotify.com/download/spotify-apps-api/reference/

Comment: I got the tip from someone on Spotify to use the sp.core.showAuthDialog and then I used the Inspector console to figure out the rest. Now I got an official answer and updated documentation below so it is probably best to use it, however it doesn't seem to work just yet..